# arxiv emergency stop not found

Tags: arxiv

I am trying to upload a paper and its giving me error. i checked the tex file and its compiling perfectly on my computer. I wonder if any one had the same issue and knows how to fix it.

```
Package pdftex.def Error: File `ZurekD.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
... 

l.309 \includegraphics[width=4 in]{ZurekD.pdf}

? 
! Emergency stop.
... 

l.309 \includegraphics[width=4 in]{ZurekD.pdf}

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on EmergentEntanglementGeometry.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'EmergentEntanglementGeometry.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'EmergentEntanglementGeometry.aux' (1549483535 >= 1549483535)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/2567556/ && tex 'EmergentEntanglementGeometry.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./EmergentEntanglementGeometry.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[11pt]{amsart}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[11pt]{amsart}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on EmergentEntanglementGeometry.log.

[verbose]: tex 'EmergentEntanglementGeometry.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/2567556/ && tex 'EmergentEntanglementGeometry.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./EmergentEntanglementGeometry.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[11pt]{amsart}
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[11pt]{amsart}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on EmergentEntanglementGeometry.log.

[verbose]: tex 'EmergentEntanglementGeometry.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'EmergentEntanglementGeometry.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Comment: the error seems quite clear you are including the file `ZurekD.pdf` but it can not be found, are you sure it's in the right place in your submission?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! There are two errors, apparenlty: The first is the `ZurekD.pdf` which was not found. The second is that the system is running (plain) `tex 'EmergentEntanglementGeometry.tex'`, but the file starts with a LaTeX command. Try to have the system run `pdflatex` instead of `tex`.